# List issue in python : how to except one value before product of remaining all

Tags: list-comprehension

I have a list of items. I want to replace first item with product of remaining items of list except first. Do the same for remaining all. How can i do that?

```
lst = [2,3,5,4,7]
```

Output should be :

```
New_lst = [420,280,168,210,120]
```

Comment: Do you have some code that demonstrates an attempt at this problem? Can you please add comments to that code to explain the reasoning behind it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get the product:

```
>>> import math
>>> p = math.prod([2,3,5,4,7])
>>> p
840
```

Then divide all numbers by the product:

```
>>> lst = [2,3,5,4,7]
>>> New_lst = [p//i for i in lst]
>>> New_lst
[420, 280, 168, 210, 120]
```